# Files created in /var/www/website.com/public_html contain 600 permissions

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server

I have created a virtual hosts configuration and the file permissions are not inheriting correctly. I have set the permissions as follows:

/var/**www**

[image]

/var/www/**example.com**

[image]

/var/www/example.com/**public_html**

[image]

/var/www/example.com/public_html/index.html

[image]

Note: index.php is generated with ***600*** file permissions and not ***775*** permissions like its parent. I have attempted to delete all folders and files all the way down to var/www and re-establish permissions to ensure steps properly and the files are still being generated with ***600*** permissions.

---

**EDIT > SOLUTION:**

Because new files were being created via FTP, this issue was not related to the files folder permissions but rather VSFTPD's ***configuration*** and how it was assigning new files permissions generated via FTP.  All the credit goes to [gurcanozturk](/questions/tagged/gurcanozturk)'s answer on [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15309/new-added-files-has-been-setted-chmod-600-via-ftp) for the commands and pointing me in the correct direction. Below are the few steps for this specific scenario.

Open VSFTPD configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Near the top, add (0755 being *questionable*)

```
file_open_mode=0755
```

And ***uncomment*** out

```
local_umask=022
```